# Resize my Home ext4 partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning

I ve been trying to resize my ubuntu partition(`/sda9`) with the  unallocated space (11.72GB) , I tried Gparted (`pic1`) but It seems that I can't add the unallocated space `pic2`

Can you please tell me the problem .?

Thanks !

pic1 : [image]

pic2 : [image]

Comment: I don't see any unallocated space next to sda9. The 11.72GB you've mentioned is way behind sda5, and can not be easily added to sda9.

Comment: You'll have to move sda5 first, so that the unalocated space is between sda5 and sda9

Comment: Yes I am booted from Live CD ! @CharlesGreen  How to move it ?

Comment: Choose the option to `resize/move` on /dev/sda5 - change the value in the box reading `Free space preceding` to 11720 to get 11.72 GiB

Comment: @CharlesGreen It take me some time to do that, but it worked ! Thanks :d

Comment: @CharlesGreen Can you add your comment as an answer to choose yours !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the empty space to the partition that you want (`sda9`) you will need to first move partition `sda5` so that the empty space is contiguous, or next to, the target partition.

Using `gparted`, select `/dev/sda5` and choose the option `resize/move` - change the value in the box reading Free space preceding to 11720 to get 11.72 GiB.  This will place the empty space available before partition `/dev/sda5`, and next to partition `/dev/sda9`.  When this operation has completed, you will be able to choose the `resize/move` option of `/dev/sda9` and increase the size of that partition to fill the unallocated space.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Your free space follows sda5, not sda9, so it can not be expanded into it.  You would need to move sda5 to the right so that the free space precedes it and follows sda5 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to unmount a partition first in order to resize it.  If you are resizing your system partition you need to boot from a live cd/usb and then resize it.  Gparted is included in Ubuntu 14.04/14.10.  You can also create a standalone Gparted bootable cd/usb from the Gparted ISO found here:  http://gparted.org/download.php.

:) Best of luck!