# Can't resize partition to unallocated ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Here I have my Ubuntu OS on `/dev/sda7` and I would like to allocated to the unallocated partition [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Vni.png), but I am unable to expand my `sda7` into unmounted.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Boot a 'live' system (eg. install media), then you will be able to re-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GParted won't let me edit a partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643858/gparted-wont-let-me-edit-a-partition) You can't resize a mounted partition and the partition has to be mounted in order to run the system and so you have to use a USB or DVD live session like the one you probably used to install Ubuntu with and choose "try Ubuntu without installing" and then follow the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/643866/167115

Answer (score 0):

The lock icon next to `/dev/sda7` shows that it's mounted, therefore un-modifiable. Since `/dev/sda7` is mounted at `/`, you won't be able to `umount` it from your current system. You'll have to boot from a "Live USB/Live CD" distribution, then you can use `gparted` to extend `/dev/sda7` (which won't be mounted),

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This answer contains some incorrect information as explained by the comment below.**

From what I gather, you are wanting to add unallocated disk space that you left from being unsure of how much you should give Linux vs. Windows.

With LVM, it's become possible to extend or shrink a mounted ext4 partition. Since you have a separate partition for your pagefile I'm pretty sure you're not running LVM which may lead to some confusion with more recent documentation. You should use a live CD so you can resize the unallocated space towards your unmounted ext4 partition.

Some previous solutions that may help you:

[Resize my Home ext4 partition with unallocated space](https://askubuntu.com/a/548379/913404)

[Unallocated space, how to resize /home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/a/143529/913404)

Comment: LVM has nothing to do with being able to exdend or shrink mounted partitions. It's limitation of filesystem itself. ext4 can be grown while it is mounted but you can't shrink it. On the other hand, btrfs supports online resizing (both growing and shrinking) and you don't need LVM for that at all. LVM might help though, by abstracting out your free space, so there is no need to move partitions.